# crm2011 Upgrade a managed solution zip failed

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

When I upgrade an existing managed solution on crm 2011,

1. The two options 'Maintain Customization' and 'Overwrite Customization' did not show up on the Deployment Wizard.
2. the 'Next' button is disabled.

See the following picture.

[image: Deployment Wizard]

Thanks in advance

the following information are from the Import Log. I am confused whether it succeeded or failed?

There are two tabs.

1. On the solution Tab

Status  Processed
Message Customizations have been imported successfully.
Progress [%]    100.00
Duration [s]    43.1

2. On the Component Tab--- one failure

18:18:13.03 SDK Message Processing Step {a3459424-885d-e411-8e4b-005056920049}  Invoice.Plugins.PDFInvoice: Create pdfinvoice Invoice.Plugins.PDFInvoice: Create of pdfinvoice  Processed   0x80045043  The original sdkmessageprocessingstep has been disabled and replaced.

Finally, I checked changes on the destination environment. I found that changes in managed solution zip have been applied to crm 2011. I guess the import is sucessful, but why?

Comment: Click the Download Log File and share with us the contents.

Comment: I have added some info from the Import Log.

Comment: the import turned out to be not failed, but I can't understand what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import was successful (see the 100% progress). If there would be any error, you will never reach 100%.

The entry in the component tab is not an error, but a warning. During the import there were also changes applied to an existing plugin. The update process will replace the existing step(s) and will recreated them according to the content of the imported solution. This entry tells you simply that it is not exactly the same steps as before.

So what you see here is the normal behavior when importing a solution which contains a plugin.

Comment: Thanks. but why the 'Maintain Customization' and 'Overwrite Customization' option did not show up in the deployment wizard?

Comment: Did you try the same process with IE? Where does the log file come from?

Comment: Yeah, it works on IE. The log file is the same as the one on Chrome.